# Выполнение JS внутри div с display:none

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не смог найти информацию, но хочется освежить в памяти следующий момент.
Имеем какую-то HTML структуру. JS в виде интеграции с внешним сервисом.

```
<html>
...
 <div style="display:none">
   <script src="..."></script>
 </div>
...
</html>
```

Верно ли утверждение, что браузер по мере загрузки DOM будет выполнять все встречаемые элементы <scrip></script>? Если да - тогда в чем отличие `display:none` от `visible:hide`?

Основная суть вопроса: как отложить загрузку `<script>` до выполнения условия (например наличие класса в body /или/ проверка значения в `localStorage`)?

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` и `$(document).ready()` не в счет. Так как логика завязана на внешний скрипт

Answer (score 1):

> Верно ли утверждение, что браузер по мере загрузки DOM будет выполнять все встречаемые элементы ?

Не проверял, но предположу, что да, верно. Впрочем, вы можете проверить это сами. Я свое предположение обосновываю следующей частью ответа.

> Если да - тогда в чем отличие display:none от visible:hide

`display:none` убирает элемент из базового потока. При этом в DOM-дереве элемент все равно остается. `visibility: hidden` в прямом смысле делает элемент невидимым. Сравните:

Ничего не трогал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`display: none`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`visibility: hidden`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Основная суть вопроса: как отложить загрузку  до выполнения условия (например наличие класса в body /или/ проверка значения в localStorage)?

Обычно, конечно, так не делается в современном фронтенде. Подобные вещи - асинхронная загрузка скрипта on-demand - выполняются на уровне бандлера: code-splitting, tree-shaking и т.п. вещи.

Если же вы твердо уверены, что вам нужно именно то, что вы написали, то смотрите в сторону динамического добавления элемента `script` на страницу. Раньше иногда действительно именно так и делали. Встраивали в рантайме элемент `script` с каким-то содержимым на страницу, и только после этого сам скрипт начинал исполняться.